# onSelectNotification method of flutter_local_notifications called immediately on page start in Android (in iOS no such issue)

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In my app I am using flutter_local_notifications plugin and **onSelectNotification** method triggered immediately in Android when page started, even if you don't click the notification.

This is how my initState looks:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
final android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
final iOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
final initSettings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: iOS);

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings,
    onSelectNotification: _onSelectNotification);

 }
```

my **_onSelectNotification** notification located outside of the build method

**In iOS everything works perfectly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just added a flag for handling this case:

```
bool flagDueNotificationIssue = true; //called once when page opened for the first time

_onSelectNotification(){  
   if (Platform.isAndroid && flagDueNotificationIssue) {
      flagDueNotificationIssue = false;
      return;
    }

.... task to do when notification clicked
}
```

So when this function triggered for the first time it will not work (i.e. so it helps to resolve the first fake call of this function), in other cases, it will work as expected.